# text font-size attr was invalid when invoked paper.setViewBox() on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, svg, raphael

```
window.onload = function(){
    var r = Raphael("world", 500, 500);
    r.text(100, 100, "US").attr({
        "font-size": 5
    });
    r.setViewBox(0, 0, 300, 300, false); //remove this line, chrome will work fine.    
}
```

the font size of text was 12px(chrome default minimum font size), rather than 5px.
I added the css about *{-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}, but it didn't work.
the issue occur on chrome 537.22 version

Answer (score 0):

`.attr()` is for HTML attributes. Use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css) for this.

```
r.text(100, 100, "US").css({
        "font-size": 5
    });
```

Comment: .attr() is a Raphael Element attribute, it isn't a jquery method.